# Cordova ios 6.0.0 and 6.1.0 doesn't add all required icons to the .ipa file

Tags: cordova, cordova-ios

I created fresh test project and build it under two platforms: cordova-ios@5.1.1 and cordova-ios@6.1.0:

```
cordova create test test
cd test
cordova platform add ios@5.1.1 # or ios@6.1.0
cordova build ios --device
```

Now i have two .ipa files. The problem is that:

- **ios@5.1.1** ipa contains all required icons, 25 icon files inside the Payload directory;
- but **ios@6.1.0** contains ONLY TWO files: `AppIcon76x76@2x~ipad.png` and `AppIcon60x60@2x.png`. After uploading to the App Store it show me empty icons.

I do not have any special configuration in xcode, in xcode resources all icons displayed correctly.

I already spent two days trying various options but had no success.

Could somebody help me to understand why it so?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<widget id="" version="3.6.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <name></name>
    <description>
    </description>
    <content src="index.html" />

    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />

    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="latest" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="latest" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="latest" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebasex" spec="https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex#cli_build" />

    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />

        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/icon-20.png" width="20" height="20" />
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/icon-20@2x.png" width="40" height="40" />
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/icon-20@3x.png" width="60" height="60" />
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/icon-24@2x.png" width="48" height="48" />
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/icon-27.5@2x.png" width="55" height="55" />
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/icon-29.png" width="29" height="29" />
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/icon-29@2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/icon-29@3x.png" width="87" height="87" />
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/icon-44@2x.png" width="88" height="88" />
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" height="167" />
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/icon-86@2x.png" width="172" height="172" />
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/icon-98@2x.png" width="196" height="196" />
        <icon src="resources/ios/icons/icon-1024.png" width="1024" height="1024" />

        <preference name="scheme" value="app" />
        <preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
    </platform>

    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
</widget>
```

Comment: show your config.xml

Comment: @Eric I updated post with config.xml.